# getting Authorisation Failure response from

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am trying to search Companies House database using Java call, i am using the credential which they passed me but still i am getting error response as Authorisation failure. below is the response which i am sending. Can anybody look into it?

Here is the link which i am using as a [request](http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/examples/namesearch_req.xml) and [response](http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/examples/namesearch_reply.xml)

Comment: Where are you sending it, how are you sending it, what error are you getting, etc etc

Comment: @Peter: I am hitting companieshouse XML Gateway and i am sending it through XML content.My error message is like following, it seems i am failing to convert my password in MD5 string properly.

Comment: you still haven't provided anything useful. all you've said is "Something is wrong when I try to send X somewhere". P.s. who's Peter?